# Data Duplication Issue in AngularJS Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, fetch

I'm encountering a data duplication issue in my AngularJS application, and I'm having trouble identifying the root cause. I've thoroughly reviewed my code and followed suggestions from various sources, but the problem persists. Here's a description of my situation:

I have an AngularJS application where I'm fetching data from a JSON source using $http.get. The data is stored in $rootScope.units and is used to display various work items. Each work item has properties such as uName, name, and others.

The issue I'm facing is that for some work items, the data is being duplicated, leading to incorrect information being displayed. I've double-checked the JSON data, and the uName values are unique.

I've already taken the following steps to troubleshoot:

- Verified data fetching and storage, and the fetched data appears to be correct.
- Checked the route configuration to ensure correct parameter passing.
- Used console.log statements to trace data as it flows through controllers and templates.
- Verified the usage of data within directives and templates.
- Despite these efforts, the duplication problem remains unresolved. I suspect that there might be an - interaction or subtlety that I'm missing.

Here's a simplified version of the code structure I'm using:

```
// Sample data fetching
$http.get('data/works.json').success(function (data) {
    $rootScope.units = data.works;
});

// Sample template code for displaying work items
<div ng-repeat="unit in units">
    <a ng-click="callPortfolio(unit, $index)" href="#">{{ unit.name }}</a>
</div>
```

Could someone please guide me on how to systematically diagnose and resolve this issue? Any insights, debugging tips, or suggestions for common pitfalls to watch out for would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: #1 recommendation would be to move off of AngularJS. Fully deprecated as of January 2022. Outside of that, good luck!